# why is there a read lock in the conn read method?

Tags: go

In the golang net package https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go#L140
there is a readlock.
Can someone explain the purpose of that lock? Presumably each connection is unique between a client and a server, so one should not expect multiple read attempts from different threads? I am alos assuming that there is a go routine handler for each connection.

```
 func (fd *netFD) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if err := fd.readLock(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer fd.readUnlock()
```

no lock for efficiency

Comment: `conn := ...; go func(){conn.Read()}; go func(){conn.Read()}` one connection, multiple concurrent reads. Nothing is stopping it, so the lock is there to ensure it's at least sequential and not interleaved.

Comment: You are showing me code that explains the merit of a lock. I am interested to see a use case that merits a lock, not in a theoretical general way, but in a real scenario.  What is the use case of launching multiple go routines that perform the same read operation?

Comment: That's a whole other question, you might want to edit your post if that's what you're asking. The question you asked is why there's a lock there, and the answer is because it's possible to call `Read` concurrently.

Answer (score 6):

> I am also assuming that there is a goroutine handler for each connection.

This assumption is unjustified. Using connections in multiple goroutines is explicitly allowed:

> Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.

https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn

Comment: I guess  I am struggling to find a use case where I would launch multiple go-routines that read the same connection or for that matter write to the connection while reading from it. Perhaps the use case is a situation where the client is sending multiple read requests and the readlock is preventing a read, while another go routine has not finished sending its response. But then again read and write buffers are seperate buffers.

Answer (score -1):

when you have multiple pieces of code (called goroutines) reading from the same place, like a network connection, you need to make sure they don't interfere with each other. Imagine you have a party line where everyone can talk at once. It would be chaos if everyone tried to talk over each other!

So, the `readLock` and `readUnlock` methods in the `netFD` struct are like a special lock on the door to the place everyone is trying to read from. Before someone starts reading, they have to grab the lock. This ensures that only one person can read at a time. It's like saying, "*Hey, I'm going to read now, so nobody else can until I'm done.*"

```golang
func (fd *netFD) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if err := fd.readLock(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer fd.readUnlock()
    // read operation here
}
```